# Is it okay to rehome a 2 month old kitten if it's weaned, but still suckling off mum occasionally?

Tags: cats, feeding, junior-pets, weaning

I have a 2 month old kitten (from a litter of 6). All the kittens from the litter are still with mum, are eating kibble and wet food. Boy in question is pretty big compared to the rest of the litter. Not that it makes difference here really, I'm assuming?

But anyhow, he is due to go to a loving home shortly, my best friend is adopting him, but he still suckles off of mum occasionally.

He is the biggest mumma's boy. Is it okay to give away a kitten that still occasionally nurses off mum? Would he have any problems after removing him and taking him way from his mum and siblings while still occasionally nursing or should he be 100% weaned and off mum's milk completely before adoption? If anyone has any personal experiences or advice I'd appreciate it greatly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a little side note: Kittens often "suckle" even after they are completely weaned (without actually drinking milk or needing the milk they might drink). This is a comforting gesture comparable to human babies sucking on a pacifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait until 3 - 3 and a half months before sending your little kitten off. He should be completely off his mother’s milk and should be able to walk and play already. Another thing is that teaching tricks should be done from kitten hood. When teaching tricks, make sure you award them by treats.

If your friend has another pet, keep them away from the kitten until a few days after the kitten knows all of the houses’s area. make sure they show no aggression to each other and let the dog and kitten scent each other’s scent by putting the other pet’s toys with the kitten or the kitten’s towels to the other pet.

Once he arrives there, keep him in one room for a few days, then let him roam around that floor for another few days then slowly week by week introduce the rest of the house.

Hope your kitten moves safely into his new home soon!